# Call a controller from another controller in spring boot

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring-boot, controller

I am pretty new to spring boot and currently I'm stuck in a situation.

I have 2 controller methods

**IndexController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/openxml", params = "btnTransform", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String transformXml(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        try {
            String fileContent = request.getParameter("code1").replaceAll("&", "&amp;");
            String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
            InputStream is1 = IOUtils.toInputStream(fileContent,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            InputStream is2 = IOUtils.toInputStream(fileContent,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            String htmlString=xmlOperation.simpleTransform(is1,  fileName);
            if (htmlString.equals("")){
                model.addAttribute("message", "Please validate your XML!!");
            }            
            model.addAttribute("htmlString",StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(htmlString));
            model.addAttribute("fileContent", fileContent);
            model.addAttribute("fileName",fileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return "greeting";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/updatexpath", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
        @ResponseBody
        public String updateXPath(@RequestParam("xml") String xml, @RequestParam("xPath") String xPath, @RequestParam("editedText") String editedText){
            xml=xml.replaceAll("&", "&amp;");
            InputStream is = IOUtils.toInputStream(xml, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            String editedXml=xmlOperation.updatePara(is, xPath, editedText);
            editedXml=editedXml.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");
            return editedXml; 
 }
```

What I am doing here is call the updateXPath method from ajax and get the editedXml and update a textarea. After that I want to call the transformXml method(without any button click). Is it possible? If yes, how?? If no, any work around??

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: do you need to put the xml in the textarea? Because if you immediately go to another controller after response you can also use a redirect in your controller to go to `transformXml` and give `editedXml` inside.

Comment: Yes @Patrick, I do need that xml in the textarea

Answer (score 4):

One solution could be to use a redirections in your controller. So you can jump from one `@RequestMapping` to another.

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        String xml = "simpleXML";

        return "redirect:/transformXML?xml=" + xml;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/transformXML")
    public String transformXML(@RequestParam("xml") String xml){
        System.out.println(xml);
        //add xml to your model for the textarea.
        //transform your xml
        return xml;
    }

}
```

Hitting `http://localhost:8080/` will create a String and redirect to `http://localhost:8080/xml` including the paramter you need.

You can deceide if it enough for you to just show the `editedXml` in the textarea after `transform`.

Comment: I have a large xml and I don't want to pass it in url. Also I tried this and it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of way for you.

First way. Use `Async` support in spring. Async support can add a `Runnable` to a executor, so that, you can return a response in a request, and start a task. Here is the [async guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/). And put all your transformXml code to a `service`

Second way. Just use a javascript to send another request.(I will use this way)

Just like:

```
1. send request of updatexpath
2. wait until server response xml
3. update dom and put your xml to textarea
4. send request of transformXml
```

Comment: I tried this.. The problem with this approach is that while sending request to transform, I get the old data(not the updated data) as only the DOM is updated and not the source.

Comment: By read your code, I have no idea what you intent to do. would you tell me what is your original requirement of this code? And I'd like to suggest you to read some article about SRP(Single Responsibility principle) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle